# RSA and find 'd'

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic

So, my task is to find d if $p=5, q=11, e=17$.
Here I've tried:

- Find $n=p\cdot q = 5*11 = 55$
- Find $\phi(n) = (p-1)(q-1)=(5-1)(11-1) = 40$
- Euclidean algorithm:
  $$
  40=2\cdot 17+6
  \\
  17 = 2\cdot 6 + 5
  \\
  6 = 1*5 + 1
  $$
- The last one
  $$
  6-1*5=1
  \\
  6 - 1(17-2\cdot 6)=1
  \\
  (40-2\cdot 17) - 1(17-2\cdot(40-2\cdot 17))
  $$
  The next step is to simplify the expression, and get something like $e\cdot d + \phi(n)\cdot x = 1$. 
  But how can I get such simplified expression? I've tried to open brackets etc, but I haven't got such expression.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: the last line $=1$. Remove the brackets and group the $40$ and $17$ terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\left(40-2\cdot 17\right) - 1\cdot\left[17-2\cdot\left(40-2\cdot17\right)\right] &= 1\\
40-2\cdot 17 - 17 + 2\cdot 40 -4\cdot 17 &= 1\\
3\cdot 40 -7\cdot17 &= 1
\end{align*}$$

---

Or break the brackets early, which I usually prefer:
$$\begin{align*}
6-1\cdot5 &= 1\\
6-1\cdot(17-2\cdot 6) &= 1\\
3\cdot6-1\cdot 17 &= 1\\
3\cdot(40-2\cdot 17)-1\cdot17 &= 1\\
3\cdot 40 -7\cdot17 &= 1
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Oh you, how has you done it?! So we have $2\cdot 40 + 40 = 3\cdot 40 $ and we have $17+2\cdot 17 + 4\cdot 17$. Awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify what 'd' is?
Anyway, from my interpretation of d (I think it is an integer such that $17d+40x=1$).
$$gcd(17,40)=(m,n)\\=>gcd(17,6)=(m,n-2m)\\=>gcd(5,6)=(m-2(n-2m),n-2m)=(5m-2n,n-2m)\\=>gcd(5,1)=(5m-2n,3n-7m)$$ Therefore $3n-7m=1=>3*40-7*17=1$. Hence $d=-7$

Comment: $e$ is the encryption key and $d$ is the corresponding decryption key.